# Javascript Number Storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to make a Calculator and save the numbers in Javascript LocalStorage but the following Code don't work.

```
const x = [24];

function test() {
  for (let i = 4; i > 0; i--) {
    if (i == 1) {
      localStorage.setItem(0, x[0]);
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem(i);
      localStorage.setItem(i, x[i - 1]);
      console.log(i);
      console.log(x[i - 1]);
    }
  }
}
```

My goal is that the numbers are "moving" the numbers so that when i click on the Button "Calculate" that the numbers are for example moving from Array `[1, 35, 12, 35, 13]` to Array `[new Number, 1, 35, 12, 35]`. I want to make like a history for the last 5 Numbers and always the 6th will delete. But i don't know how to do it and i tried a lot

I tried to change the code, i made a if statement but it always didn't work

Comment: Instead of using a separate local storage item for each number, just save the entire array as JSON in a single item.

Comment: You can then use `x.push()` to add an element to the end, and `x.unshift()` to insert an element at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Read once, write when updated

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/uv3a8cdz/)

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // when page loads
  const arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("arr") || '[]'); // load or create
  const saveNumber = num => {
    arr.unshift(num); // add to start
    if (arr.length === 6) arr.pop(); // remove from end
    localStorage.setItem("arr",JSON.stringify(arr));
  };
  // delegate from button container
  document.getElementById("calculator").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target.closest("button.num"); // what was clicked?
    if (!tgt) return; // only handle number buttons
    saveNumber(+tgt.textContent);
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="calculator">
  <button class="num">1</button> 
  <button class="num">2</button> 
  <button class="num">3</button> 
  <button class="num">4</button> 
  <button class="num">5</button> 
  <button class="num">6</button> 
  <button class="num">7</button> 
  <button class="num">8</button> 
  <button class="num">9</button> 
  <button class="num">0</button> 
</div>
```